# How to get Id number co chaincode of hyperledger fabric by Hyperledger Fabric SDK for node.js?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After I installed the chaincode, the peer chaincode list return all installed chaincode with the id numbers:

```
peer chaincode list --installed -C mychannel                                                                                                                                         
Get installed chaincodes on peer:
Name: dev-mychaincode-cc, Version: alpha1, Path: /opt/home/mychaincode-cc, Id: 414955ccc11a2644a7f7caxxxb29ee06
```

Is there anyway to get this id (414955ccc11a2644a7f7caxxxb29ee06) by Hyperledger Fabric SDK for node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call the **GetInstalledChaincodes** transaction function on the **lscc** system chaincode, and parse the return value, which is a [ChaincodeQueryResponse](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/protos.html#protos-ChaincodeQueryResponse) protocol buffer (protobuf) message.

The protobuf definitions for Fabric are in the [fabric-protos](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos) repository. There are also published Go, Node (TypeScript/JavaScript) and Java language bindings for all the Fabric protobufs that you can use directly to help unpack protobuf messages:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/

For reference, the lscc chaincode's GetAllChaincodes transaction function implementation is here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/2b8997153a4d7ea94429b23f9868eb937bce35b5/core/scc/lscc/lscc.go#L613